# Passport.js NestJS React Google OAuth2 | How to get on frontend data from google auth callback?

Tags: reactjs, authorization, nestjs, passport.js

I have backend (`localhost:5000`) and frontend (`localhost:3000`)
I have a passport strategy `google-oauth20` and it works well.

My auth url on backend is `localhost:5000/auth/google` and callback url is `localhost:5000/auth/google/callback`.
I call auth url from React app(simply `window.href`) and then when all goes ok I get to callback url, where my backend create/login user and result of this is jwt token that returns in response.

So my question is - how to send to frontend this data to finally authenticate user?
I tried to modify backend route `localhost:5000/auth/google/callback` to not return response but redirect to frontend page with `req.header.Authorization` + `token` token but this doesn't work.

Comment: how to implement passport's successRedirect with nestjs?